# How to start/stop downloads in Azureus (Vuze) via terminal?

Tags: 11.04, command-line, bittorrent

I need to stop/start download through shell script in Azureus(Vuze).
I know there is CLI and I can invoke it as

```
java -jar Azureus2-XXX.jar --ui=console
```

The `?` will show a list of commands I can use. To get a list of torrents,

```
show torrents
```

etc. But it is **CLI**. I need shell script to do that so How I can use it to stop/start downloads through shell script?

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I found Flush which has command-line options which does my job but it has very less functionality compared to others.

I use [`Flush`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flush/) to start or stop torrent downloads of running instance through terminal.

I can use these options with flush.

```
  --start={all,downloads,uploads}     Start torrents  
  --stop={all,downloads,uploads}      Stop torrents
```

*note: I didn't find anyway to do this in Vuze.*

Answer (score 1):

### This solution works flawlessly

OK. So building up on my previous answer, here is a solution that works right out of the box without any hassle.

First, install this plugin in Vuze: [Azureus HTML WebUI](http://plugins.vuze.com/plugin_details.php?plugin=azhtmlwebui)

Now, go to your browser and open http://localhost:6886/. This is a web UI for controlling your Vuze. Here, you can see that to pause/resume downloads, you have a link with such URL:

```
http://localhost:6886/index.tmpl?act=pause
```

Now, you can simply "click" this url using CURL by making a GET request. Hence, fire up these commands in the terminal for pausing and resuming:

```
curl --request GET 'http://localhost:6886/index.tmpl?act=pause'   # For pausing
curl --request GET 'http://localhost:6886/index.tmpl?act=resume'  # For resuming
```

Comment: Why didn't you edit your original post?

Comment: In my original post I've suggested using the Python API but it isn't working right now. I am testing that API and will update that answer if it works. This answer focuses on an easier method using a different plugin. I could have included this answer in my original post, but considered it better to have a different answer, as this is a completely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in Vuze using a workaround. I haven't tried the solution but it should work.

First, go here: http://plugins.vuze.com/plugin_list.php and look in the "Remote Access" section of Vuze plugins. There are a few plugins here which can help:

1. "Vuze Web Remote" should be good for our case. This plugin helps you control Vuze using web-based UI. Now, it also provides access to RPC methods (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:9091/vuze/rpc?json=%7B%22method%22%3A%22torrent-start-all%22%7D). 
   So, you can just ping this link using some Python script and it should work. You should be able to toggle your Vuze now.
2. "Python Library" provides API to control Vuze. You can use this API directly and write a Python script to control Vuze.

Comment: I'll post results later on after trying this solution.

Comment: I have posted another solution, which works flawlessly and smoothly.

Answer (score -4):

I've never used vuze with Ubuntu, but in Windows you highlight the torrent and click stop/start.

Like I said I have only used it with windows.

Comment: This works in Ubuntu too, but this question is not about how to start and stop torrents *in Vuze's graphical user interface*. Instead, it's about how to start and stop them from the command-line or in a shell script.